# How to make pulse around image in a website?

Tags: jquery, html, pulse

I want to have a pulse around my logo for my site. Check out what I mean here (http://www.bearsfightingbears.com/) and look at the bear image on the left side. I have examined the source and I haven't been able to find any solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do a find search on pulse in this their style sheet:
http://bearsfightingbears.com/assets/blog.build-07385bf2aa5991b00ac5d4a0e694b833.css